# Using Submin without mail?

Tags: sendmail, svn

I want to implement the user administration for an SVN server with Submin. The network configuration is restricted: it is not allowed to send mails. Now I see two ways:

1. Is it possible to reconfigure Submin so that it does not require user registration mails?
2. Is it possible to separate the "view part" from the user data / SVN, so that it resides on another Apache instance (allowed to send mails)?

How to achieve this? Or would you advise against it entirely and open the port for sSMTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I wrote a bash script that puts the activation link into a text file (instead of trying to send it via email) for the first user.
2. I deactivated all the mail stuff in the submin source (password request mails, post-commit hooks, etc.).

The drawback: in case of a forgotten password, one hast to contact the admin, which is ok for now.